# Cannot open blendfile after crash

Tags: sculpting, blend-files

I spent a few hours sculpting, then I set the view to ***render view*** button and blender instantly crashed. The blendfile is also refusing to open. I tried to remove "Load UI" but that didnt help. What should I do?

Comment: Can you attach the file?

Comment: Hello :). You can open a new Blender instance and go *File > Append* the whole scene or collection.